# Error python al insertar una imagen a un label

Tags: python, imagen

Al agregar una imagen a una Label, aparece este error, podria alguien ayudarme a solucionarlo?, los dos archivos se encuentran dentro del mismo directorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje dice que no reconoce el contenido del archivo. Obviamente, el programa fue capaz de abrir y leer el archivo.

Comment: Eso quiere decir que esta dañada la imagen o que tengo que hacer?

Comment: ¿Mirarla con algun visor de imagenes?

Comment: Prueba con una jpg, quizás no reconozca el formato png

Comment: Ya lo hice y nada que me funciona

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola amigo tengo una alternativa si aun presentas el error.
Prueba utilizando PILLOW para abrir la imagen

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding=10)
frame.grid()

title = ttk.Label(frame, text="Fix Tkinter error SO").grid(column=0, row=0)

img = Image.open("prueba.png")
img = img.resize((200, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)

label_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
ttk.Label(frame, image=label_image).grid(column=1, row=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ok, muchas gracias, lo hice de esa manera y si funciono, al final no supe porque ocurría el error pero se soluciono, muchas gracias

Comment: Es posible que tu versión de Tkinter aun no tenga soporte para los pngs y pillow si